# Modernizr class cannot be detected in webpage that is stored inside a secured folder?

Tags: css, asp.net, class, security, modernizr

i've a master page/baseform page that is being inherited by other webpages in the project. I have a folder that is set-up as secured which where the webpage such as login page are stored. I've put-up modernizr to help me fix styles problems, i've put it in the master page. In the master page, i've a stylesheet there that is being used generally for the whole website. classes that are created by modernizr are detected by the webpages that are in just inside the project's folder, meaning it is not inside another folder. But the webpages that are inside another folder, such as the login page unable to detect or see the classes. why?
**here's a illustration of how my project heirarchy looks like and some screenshots to help describe my problem:**

1. Project Name

   - Secured Folder

     - Login Page - unable to detect modernizr classes
   - Master Page - where modernizr was placed
   - Index Page - able to detect modernizr classes

Markup for MasterPage

```
<html class="no-js" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
<link href="/css/index_1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/scripts/modernizr.development.js"></script>
```

Index Page Markup - there's the modernizr classes
[image: Index Page Markup - there's the modernizr classes]
Index Page control that uses the modernizr class of no-ponterevents
[image: Index Page control that uses the modernizr class of no-pointerevents]
Login Page Markup - you can see that there's the modernizr classes
[image: Login Page Markup - you can see that there's the modernizr classes]
Login Page control that has the same class with the control in the Index Page but the no-pointerevents class was not detected
[image: Login Page control where it uses the same class with the one in the Index Page]

Comment: can you post the document mode for both pages? It can be found in the upper right portion of the F12 tools

Comment: they're both standard.

Comment: standard what? If you could add what the document and browser modes are, it would be very helpful

Comment: Browser Mode: IE10 Document Mode: Standards

Comment: IE 10 supports pointer events, so `.no-pointerevents` should only be happening on a page rendering with ie10 document mode or below. It is really hard to help at all without being able to see the actual website. That being said, you should only be using the `no-pointerevents` class to style things that rely on pointevents, not as a generic style hook.

Comment: First based on modernizr IE10 doesn't support pointer-events, i'm confused to what you're saying. Secondly, I do have reasons on using the pointer-events. Do you have any idea or had any experience on using modernzr in a secure page? I'm guessing it has something to do with being the page encrypted that is why it was able to detect the .no-pointerevents of modernizr.